# The order of an element

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

The order of a unit $a \pmod m $ is the least $n \geq 1$ such that $a^n \equiv 1 \pmod m$.
my question is : Is true that number and its inverse have the same order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose not. Then what can you say about $a^n (a^{-1})^n \pmod m$?

Answer (score 2):

Notice that we have $\ a^n \equiv 1 \iff  (a^{-1})^n \equiv 1\ $ since $\ a^n (a^{-1})^n \equiv 1$

Thus $\ \{ n\ge 1 :\ a^n \equiv 1\} =  \{ n\ge 1\ :\ (a^{-1})^n\equiv 1\}\ $ so they have equal least element = order.

Comment: Thanks for your immediate help , but should we prove that there is no smaller power that sends a^-1 to 1 ?

Comment: @Salma Both sets are equal so their least elements are equal, i.e. the order of $a$ equals the order of $\,a^{-1}.\,$ That completes the proof.